# how to store radiobutton data in the database

Tags: java, html, jsp

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>


<head>
<title>HTML Tables</title>
</head>
<body>

<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>

<table bgcolor="lightgray" border="5" width="60%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0.5" color="blue" >
<tr>

<th colspan ="3" bgcolor="#999999"><br>


<div align="Center" > <font face="verdana" size="5" color="white"> ATTENDANCE </font> 
</div>
</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="14%"><h3>Register No</td>
<td><h3> Student Name</td>
<td><h3> Attendance</td>
</tr>

<!--  
<tr>
<td> 1 </td>
 <td> Tom </td>
<td> <input type="radio" name="rdbutton1">Present <input type="radio" name="rdbutton1">Absent
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td> Jerry </td>
<td> <input type="radio" name="rdbutton2">Present <input type="radio" name="rdbutton2">Absent
</tr>-->



<% 
Connection dbcon=null;
   
 DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
  dbcon=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl","scott","tiger");
  Statement stmt=dbcon.createStatement();
  ResultSet rst=null;
  
rst=stmt.executeQuery("select regno, name from studentreg");
while(rst.next())
{%> 
<tr>

<td><%=rst.getString("regno")%></td>

<td><%=rst.getString("name")%></td>



  
<!--  <td><%=1%></td>
<td><%=rst.getString("name")%></td>-->

<td> <input type="radio" name="rdbutton1">Present <input type="radio" name="rdbutton2">Absent
</tr>
  
<% } %> 


</table>
</body>
</html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

In this code the radiobuttons are not functions properly, all the radiobuttons are getting checked.
And how to store the present and absent values in the database.
Is there any other special dynamic tables that has to be used for these radiobuttons, or can we use with this normal table itself.

Answer (score 0):

> all the radiobuttons are getting checked

that's because each of your `radio` button has a different `name` attribute